# How do we use rails and better_errors in docker environment securely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I know we can't use [better_errors](https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors) from not localhost as default.

If we want to use better_errors in docker environment, we can use `BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '0.0.0.0/0'`.

But it has a security risk. If a malicious user accesses your host machine on the same network and the rails application raises error by some chance, he can do anything the rails application can do(ex: steal all source code).

Is there any idea to deal with the security risk?

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1. This should only be used in development environment, so this security risk would only be happening while developing code, it shouldn't affect your production/staging server.
2. You can use the predefined subnets of docker:

```
  # Private subnets defined by RFC1918 as stated in https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/
  BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '10.0.0.0/8'
  BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '172.24.0.1/12'
  BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '172.16.0.0/12'
  BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! '192.168.0.0/16'
```

Which should restrict the amount of IPs that have access to the machine itself.

Answer (score -2):

I found this solution on BetterErrors repo:
https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors/issues/270#issuecomment-236236791

In short:

1. Open the file `config/environments/development.rb`
2. Add the follow line `BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! "0.0.0.0/0"`
3. Restart your server

If you have still troubles try to start your server with rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'

I use it on Mac with Docker Machine.